# Firebase Database don't get updated in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an android studio coding to signup and the database is firebase. When I enter data to signup, those values don't get updated in the firebase database.

[image]

But the firebase authentication have updated.

[image]

Here is my coding for Signup.

```
public class DriverLogin extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mEmail, mPassword;
    private Button mLogin, mRegistration;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver_login);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        firebaseAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(DriverLogin.this, MapsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    return;
                }
            }
        };

        mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        mLogin =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.Login);
        mRegistration =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.Registration);

        mRegistration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = mPassword.getText().toString();

                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(DriverLogin.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(DriverLogin.this, "Sign up Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else {
                            String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Driver").child(user_id);
                            current_user_db.setValue(true);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about your DB structure? You can't add `child` to `Driver` because it is `variable` with `value = true`

Comment: There is no any child of Driver in your structure

Comment: I'm new to android and firebase. I'm doing this with the help of a youtube video. So can you tell me what should I do to resolve my issue.

Comment: can you explain what you want to do.? about your db structure

Comment: try `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user_id);`. it should be updated. Basically you can simulate it on your Firebase Console, you can't add `child` (or `+` symbol on `Driver`) but can on `Users`

Comment: My app mainly have 2 users (Driver, Parent). Here in this code, I'm trying to signup as a driver. So I need to update the branch under driver with my details.

Comment: ok try this DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user_id);
  current_user_db.child("Driver").setValue(true);

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @ Aashutosh Kumar that also didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue here, you are confused how to make Firebase's Database Structure.

1. Go to your `Firebase Console`, then go to `Database`
2. Hover to your `root`. In your case `bit-driver-app` and Click `+`. This is `add Child`
3. Now, I guess you want make `Driver` with many user's `UID`. So on `Name` just type `Driver` with NO value. Then click `+` again
4. Now I think this is where you want your `user_id`
5. And maybe with some of the `variable` like `name`, etc

[image: My DB Structure Suggestion]

So, Basically you can't `add child` to something that has `value`. In your case your `Driver` has `value=true`, it can't have child and won't get updated

Answer (score 0):

Thank all who helped me here with my problem.

I have found the answer and I'm posting it, may someone will get help in the future.

The firebase database rules have to set to as below.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```